# Getting File Path

Tags: javascript, python, html

I recently made a Python app where I take an Excel file, convert it to a  CSV file, and then shoot it out with an Email. I tried turning this application into a Web App and here is where issues arose. In order to send the a file using Email, I need to get the full file path and I am not sure how to get it. In order to let the user pick out the file, I used `<input type="file">`, but this only supplies me with the name of the file and not the actual file path. Any suggests on what I should do to fix this issue?

Comment: What is it that you tried using? I think a vital piece of information is missing here: "In order to send [a] file using Email, I used {?}".

Comment: Selecting a file via an `<input>` usually means uploading the file; therefore your python server should have complete control over its content. If by path you mean the path on the user's harddisk, how is that even relevant? Posting the form as `multipart/form-data` will upload the excel file to your python server, which can now convert it and send the email. If you want to send the CSV as attached file, have your server save it first in a temporary location of your choosing, then attach it. That way you'll know exactly what the path is.

Comment: Hi @JakeTae, thanks for the reply! The file path is necessary as Yagmail(the emailing package I am using) requires that you have the files file path to the User's Hard drive in order to add the file as an attachment. So, if you have any ideas on that front that would be appreciated greatly! As for the posting the form as "multipart/form-data", could you elaborate on what that does? Thanks again!

Comment: Yagmail runs on your server, which means the file sent as attachment also needs to be on the server. So the order is: 1. user selects file 2. form is sent 3. python receives file, converts to CSV, stores to *server's* hard drive 4. yagmail sends out email with file on server attached to it. There is no need anywhere to get a path; you pick one to save the CSV, then use that in your yagmail setup, period.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module in python.

```py
import os
os.path.abspath('/path/to/file')
```

Comment: Please edit and improve answer instead of downvoting.

PS. OP does not mention in which language does he need the absolute path (Python or JS).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think there's a point in improving this answer; it's most likely not as simple as calling `abspath()`, and until we now exactly what OP's issue is (and it looks as if they're not exactly clear about that themselves), posting answers is premature. It's pretty clear OP thinks their python server can somehow directly load the file from the client's hard drive, so I'm guessing there's not even a proper file upload handling in place yet.

Comment: Oh, I didn't have enough reputation to clarify. And if you guys downvote it until the OP's clear, then I'm not gonna make it :). The OP says he's a newbie in Python & JS, so most likely he has to do a lot more (reading also) than finding path before converting it to a WebApp.

Comment: Hi @joe733, 
I built the app using Glitch, so when the file is chosen it is showing as if the file belonged to the app instead of the hard drive of the user. Is there a way that I can get the file path of the file in the users hard drive?